# ASP.NET MVC checkboxes form GET long query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I have a search form with multiple checkbox controls (about 200) and I send this form using **GET** request because I need the users to be able to share their search criteria. The problem is that MVC generates the query string parameters for the checkboxes twice (once for `true` and once for `false`) and my query string goes very long (about 7000 characters), also IIS blocks my request for having too long query string. I found a way to tell IIS to allow such long query string values using this tutorial: [HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request Header too long)](https://docs.secureauth.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14778828). If I upload my app on a shared hosting, I wouldn't have access to machine registry, so this problem is blocking me completely. Have you experienced such a problem and if - how did you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: 200 checkboxes? Is that even usable? Seems you need to find an alternative way to send the data -- maybe a string of 0's and 1's indicating what's checked or unchecked, and forcing a specific order on the checkboxes? But 200 controls seems like it would just be an unusable mess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mrunion. I actually have been thinking of this idea, but if I append the query string myself by attaching to submit event of the form using jQuery and then redirecting using window.location..., the model binder stops binding the properties of my view model, specified as a parameter in the controller action (no matter what I fill in the form, the view model properties have always default values). PS. It turned out that I have "only" 96 checkboxes

Comment: You have not shown the view code, but I assume your using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` which generates 2 inputs - a `<input type="checkbox" ... value="True" />` and `<input type="hidden" ... value="False" />` You could just manually create create the html but sending that many values to a GET method is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on having that many check boxes which isn't ideal from a UX perspective then this Is how I'd go about doing it.

First thing first is I'd switch the form action to be a POST request that way you no longer have a huge GET request.

Bind the values to a simple model and then serialise and store the serialised model into a database with a unique identifier. You will then redirect the user to the results with nothing but the unique identifier in the GET request. You will then be able to quickly fetch the search criteria from the DB and deserialise it and return the search results.

This means they will be able to share the results without having massive long queries.